Задача на использование списковых включений из самоучителя по Python
Задача.
Используя списковые включения вывести следующий список:
[[2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7, 8]]

Без списковых включений решил задачу следующим образом:
result = []
for k in range(4):
    new_list = []
    for i in [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9][k:-4 + k]:
        new_list.append(i)
    result.append(new_list)

Пытался по этому же принципу написать код с использованием списковых включений, но в результате выводится список, в котором все значения типа None.
[[].append(i) for k in range(4) for i in [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9][k:-4 + k]]


А вот не надо через append, он возвращает None и вообще не используется в списковых включениях. Вы в них должны не добавлять элементы в список, а формировать список сразу целиком.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1585240/291659

@CrazyElf Спасибо, задачу решил.

@MBo Спасибо. Увидел ответ на свой вопрос в вашем решении.

[list(range(k, k + 4)) for k in range(2, 6)]

[[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9][k:-4 + k] for k in range(4)]

Задачу решил, вопрос снят. Комментаторам спасибо.
